# jQuery - reset variable value inside .each loop

Tags: jquery

I have following script:

```
var height = 0;
$('.scroller').each(function() {

    $(this).children('div').each(function() {

        if (height < $(this).height()) {
            height = $(this).height();
        }

    });
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");

});
```

**What it does:**

- loop through each `children div` inside each `.scroller` div
- `height < $(this).height()` = if height of the currently looped `div` is bigger than `0` it is setting the height of this div as `new value of the height variable`
- this way is finding the highest div element in each `.scroller` div
- than, the height (height of the highest element ) is set to `.scroller` div

**The issue:**

- if any element inside first '.scroller' is higher than ANY element in the second `.scroller` it is setting the height (highest element in first `.scroller`) also to second `scroller` - example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/7jAAG/20/

Is element in the first `.scroller` are not higher than elements in second `.scroller` everything works fine - example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/7jAAG/16/

**I think the problem is setting the `height var` - how can I reset this value to `0` BEFORE going to loop though second `.scroller` ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding but could you not just do this:

```
$('.scroller').each(function() {
    var height = 0;
    $(this).children('div').each(function() {

        if (height < $(this).height()) {
            height = $(this).height();
        }

    });
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");

});
```

the `height` variable will then get reset for each instance of `.scroller` in the DOM that's looped through.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are after. http://jsfiddle.net/7jAAG/30/

Set `height` for each iteration of `.scroller`.

```
$('.scroller').each(function() {
    var height = 0;
    $(this).children('div').each(function() {

        if (height < $(this).height()) {
            height = $(this).height();
        }

    });
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to set height to 0 between each iteration. I don't know if the result is what you actually expect.

http://jsfiddle.net/7jAAG/24/

```
var height = 0;
$('.scroller').each(function() {

    $(this).children('div').each(function() {

        if (height < $(this).height()) {
            height = $(this).height();
        }

    });
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");
    height = 0;
});
```